# Find number of features in ArcGIS MapServer layer

Tags: arcgis-server, query, json, api

Given an ArcGIS MapServer layer URL (eg https://gis.dallascityhall.com/wwwgis/rest/services/Sdc_public/Zoning/MapServer/15), how can I find (preferably in JSON format) the number of total features in the layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, there is a "return count only" option (`returnCountOnly=1`) option, so:

```
.../query?where=1%3D1&returnCountOnly=true&f=json
```

Returns:

```
{"count":3634}
```

Comment: That's the perfect answer!